# Can't I enter hangeul with std::cin?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm working at a super-simple program that if we enters a name, and it prints the entered name. It's easy but the problem is I live in korea and it's the hangeul(korean alphabet) **so it must support hangeul**

I tried this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string name = "";
    cout << "이름을 입력하세요: "; getline(cin, name);
    cout << "당신의 이름은 " << name << "입니다.";
    return 0;
}
```

If we make it to english it will be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string name = "";
    cout << "Enter your name: "; 
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Your name is " << name << ".";
    return 0;
}
```

Looks easy. but if we put the hangeul in that `cin`,

```
Print:

Enter your name: 이름
Your name is .
```

and it just end. Of course the answer I wanted is:

```
Print:

Enter your name: 이름
Your name is 이름.
```

I've tried everything like using wide-character, change system locale and other many thing.
Here's the code I've tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Korean");

    string name = "";
    cout << "이름을 입력하세요: "; 
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "당신의 이름은 " << name << "입니다.";
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {   
    wstring name = "";
    cout << "이름을 입력하세요: "; 
    getline(wcin, name);
    wcout << "당신의 이름은 " << name << "입니다.";
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {   
    wstring name = "";
    cout << "이름을 입력하세요: "; 
    getline(wcin, name);
    cout << "당신의 이름은 ";
    wcout << name;
    cout << "입니다.";
    return 0;
}
```

If you can, please help me!

Comment: Are you sure your terminal supports these characters?

Comment: Also, are you on windows?

Comment: + If you put the `cout << (int)name.size();` middle of `getline` and `cout`, you'll see `character size`, not `character size * 3`. I think that would be related to this problem.

Comment: It's Windows, and the terminal that I using is Windows Terminal. It supports korean.
Also, I use the MinGW-GCC compiler and the code editor is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: That's why it's not visible there because it does not support these characters. But here You can see https://godbolt.org/z/esoes4Esh.

Comment: But it can print a hangeul.

Comment: Yeah, because it supports these characters, but windows terminal does not.

Comment: Problem:
`이름을 입력하세요: 이름`
`당신의 이름은 입니다.`

Comment: I do not know if it works on windows or not but you can redirect your terminal output to a file, via extending your `./program.exe > text.txt`. to see what your program generated.

Comment: I want the answer like: `이름을 입력하세요: 이름` `당신의 이름은 이름입니다.`

Comment: text.txt `이름을 입력하세요: 당신의 이름은   입니다.`

Comment: The input was `이름`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233927/discussion-between-foragerdev-and-xphere07).

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to check return value of the setlocale function, if it returns null, than it simply fails, if so try to search for another names for Korean system locale.
2. If you don't get an error in first paragraph, then check your comand prompt locale: press Windows+R, type 'cmd' and press Enter. In opened command prompt window type 'chcp' and press Enter. You should see output as shown below:

```
C:\Users\User>chcp
Active code page: 1251
```

1251 - this is mine coding page, means 'windows cp-1251'. After that google your coding page (you can find tables where each symbol placed with it's decimal representation on internet).

3. Compare some Korean symbol from your program with it's representation from coding table, you can output first symbol's decimal value like this:

```
int main () {
    string name = "";
    cout << "이름을 입력하세요: " << endl; 
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << (int)name[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If the number you get from program differs from coresponding number from your codding page, then you definitely need to search for another locale to set in your program, or to change the locale in your terminal.